# How to fix the issue that I can not delete a set of files on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have some files on my windows 10 that I want to delete, but when I try to delete them, I can not do this.

```
    PS D:\polarfire\polarfire-soc-buildroot-sdk\linux\drivers\gpu\drm\nouveau\nvkm\subdev\i2c> ls

    Directory: D:\polarfire\polarfire-soc-buildroot-sdk\linux\drivers\gpu\drm\nouveau\nvkm\subdev\i2c

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          16/09/2022    09:53           4978 aux.c
-a---          16/09/2022    09:53           1836 aux.h

PS D:\polarfire\polarfire-soc-buildroot-sdk\linux\drivers\gpu\drm\nouveau\nvkm\subdev\i2c> del aux.c
Remove-Item: Cannot find path 'D:\polarfire\polarfire-soc-buildroot-sdk\linux\drivers\gpu\drm\nouveau\nvkm\subdev\i2c\aux.c' because it does not exist.
PS D:\polarfire\polarfire-soc-buildroot-sdk\linux\drivers\gpu\drm\nouveau\nvkm\subdev\i2c>
```

When I try to delete the files, PowerShell says that it doesn't exist.

If I boot into safe mode, I am getting a similar result and I can not delete the files

## Edit1

File explorer shows this error when trying to delete the files:
[image]

Run chkdsk and still the same error.

Comment: If you view the folder in File Explorer does it display the file? Have you tried running chkdsk?

Comment: it shows the files in explorer and does not allow me to delete them.

Comment: What error dialog is displayed? What about running chkdsk?

Comment: it says that the item is not located there. Can I run chkdsk when I am using the PC?

Comment: How exactly did you run chkdsk with what parameter(s) exactly?

Comment: If the files are there and not seen to Windows, delete with Unlocker 1.92 (Major Geeks).

Comment: This is not a PS Code/feature issue, so why is this tagger PowerShell? This is an OS environment issue; you should see the same problem no matter what scripting language you use. Anyway, don't use safe mode. Boot using an OS DVD/USB into admin mode, and use the 8.3 name to find and delete/remove the file(s).

Comment: @Ramhound I used chkdsk d: should I use any other parameter?

Comment: @mans - Yes;  `chkdsk d: /r /f` What you want is it to find an issue, fix it within seconds, and at that point the file should be gone or will allow you to delete it.

Comment: @postanote I remove the PowerShell tag as suggested. Can you please elaborate on how to boot with USB? Do I need to prepare a windows bootable USB drive?

Comment: Have you tried good old cmd.exe instead of PowerShell? `aux` is a reserved word on Windows which is disallowed as file name. `aux.c` should work in general but may be some tools have problems with this name, too. In such cases cmd may work. Alternatively try WSL1 or boot into a real Linux OS as aux is a regular file-name on Linux.

Comment: @Robert I used wsl 2 and managed to delete the files. The cmd did not work. Please raise your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Please also add the reference to the fact that aux is not allowed as a file name in windows and any other name which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aux` is a reserved word on Windows which is disallowed as file name. `aux.c` should work in general but may be some tools have problems with this name, too.

The file path indicates that the file belongs to a Linux kernel driver, thus it might have been created by an Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) instance. Therefore I would also try to delete the file using WSL.

Alternatively use a Live Linux CD/USB Stick, and mount the affected partition. That way you can delete the file for sure as the file-name `aux` is nothing special on Linux.